# How to change react-router routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to change routes depending on logged in state:

```
  renderRouter() {
    if (loggedIn) {
      return (
        <Router>
          <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
        </Router>
      );
    }

    return (
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Login} />
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

But when state changes I'm receiving a warning: `Warning: [react-router] You cannot change <Router routes>; it will be ignored`

Is it possible to reinitialize react-router with new routes?

I know that I could use `onEnter` to ensure that user has access to this page, but I need to have different components in one route according to logged in state and don't want to move such logic inside of components.

Comment: is better to change component ?

Comment: Yes, I need to change component on the endpoint.

Comment: what version of react router ?

Comment: @egig, no matter. I could use any stable version which allows me to do what I want.

Comment: You need not change the Router config, instead you can set up your routes differently and perform dynamic routing based on condition like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programatically-routing-based-on-a-condition-with-react-router/44128108#44128108

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri it's not really what I need. I want to have absolutely different routes according to logged in state without any checks inside components to exclude any possiblity that user will reach secure endpoint in routing layer.

Comment: have a look at this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278322/react-new-router-after-login/45278836#45278836

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, tried and I has the same warning with it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you create two Router, I don't think you should do this.

Try wrapping your Routes in a `Switch` component which is in only one `Router`, then use the `render` props of your "main" `Route`, which will redirect you if the condition is true, use `exact` props to be sure this `Route` will match by default, notice that your `"/dashboard"` Route is above the other, so the `Switch` can match it.

The result should be like this :

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route 
      path="/"
      exact
      render={() => {
        if (loggedIn) {
          return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
        }

        return <Login />;
      }}
    />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Don't forget to import the components.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Good point about creating two routers. But this approach is still not what I need.
I want to have completely different routes according to logged in state to exclude any possibility that user can reach secured endpoint in routing layer. Also I need to have 404 for all other secured endpoints if user is not logged in and it's not really cool to add render to each Route as for me.

Comment: Maybe a `withRouter` component can help you. Anyway, I think you can find what you want here : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic There are many useful examples of what you can do with react-router. I don't know everything about it, that's the best I can do for you, sorry. :(

Answer (score 0):

I've tried few times to gain desired behavior and after all decided to change an approach of secure endpoints management. Components on my endpoints are very simple scenes which are just compose layer and some scene modules. So I've created a scene wrapper:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Login from '../scenes/Login';

function Scene({ children, fallback, secure, auth }) {
  if (secure === auth) {
    return children;
  }
  return React.createElement(fallback);
}

Scene.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.bool,
  fallback: PropTypes.func,
  secure: PropTypes.bool,
};

Scene.defaultProps = {
  auth: false,
  fallback: Login,
  secure: false,
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => ({ auth });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Scene);
```

And then in Dashboard scene:

```
import React from 'react';
import Scene from '../modules/Scene';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';

export default function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <Scene secure>
      <Layout>
        <Module1 />
        <Module2 />
      </Layout>
    </Scene>
  );
}
```